# Good Alternative to VeeBeam

Tags: lcd, hdvideo, projector

I am in he process of setting up stations in several conference rooms to allow users to bring laptops and easily connect to either a projector or large LCD.

Challenges:

- Must be driverless, or simple enough to have visitors use with minimal instruction
- Must be HD capable
- Must take both VGA and HDMI
- Needs to be wireless

I have a VeeBeam and it does a decent enough job but the two second delay is unacceptable for presentations. I have seen a number of wireless VGA and HDMI transmitters but the decent ones seem prohibitively expensive to just buy and try. Has anyone here had some experience with these devices and did you find a good one that meets the challenges above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have found, wireless isn't up to the job unless you are prepared to pay a lot - The VeeBeam is 'consumer grade' and does the intended job in its target market, but you may have to go 'professional' for what you want - if the budget allows! Here's a possible starting point:

http://www.connectivity.avocent.com/products/emerge/video_extenders.asp

I know you said 'need to be wireless', but if the issue is just having a projector some distance away from the laptop have you considered a good UTP/cat5 media extender? I use them in conference rooms where the projector is at the back of the room and the laptop/presenter's desk is at the other end. The whole setup makes use of one Rj45 wallport at the back of the room and one by the front desk.

These are the people I know can help with some decent wired kit:

http://www.keene.co.uk/

http://www.kramerelectronics.com/default.asp

http://www.rcblogic.co.uk/

http://www.adder.com/uk/default.aspx

http://www.aten.com/